# Updating MySQL DB with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using foreach to loop an array and update a MySQL database.
This is my code

```
foreach($result['getHiscore'] as $highScoreType => $highScoreValues){
        $rank = $highScoreValues['rank'];
        $lvl = $highScoreValues['lvl'];
        $totalXp = $highScoreValues['totalxp'];
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Users SET Level("$highScoreType") = $lvl,     Xp("$highScoreType") = $totalXp,  
    WHERE UserID= '1'");

}
```

i'm trying to conflate the word "level" with the contents of $highScoreType, the column titles in my DB are Leveloverall, Xpoverall, Levelattack, Xpattack and so on so i was planning on keeping the Level/Xp title constant and just changing the key.

This looks fine to me and when i tested the sql with pre-set values it updated fine, however using the variables doesn't update at all. I know that the variables are coming out of the array correctly as when i echo them inline with the foreach they print out in the correct format and order.

Is it my formatting thats the issue or am i doing missing something else?

Comment: Use single quotes for `("$highScoreType")` as in `('$highScoreType')` and do the same for the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you echo the generated SQL query that should help you see any problems in the query.

It looks odd to me: `UPDATE Users SET Level("$highScoreType") = $lvl`

Shouldn't that just be `UPDATE Users SET $highScoreType = $lvl` ?

Be aware also that this sort of code is vulnerably to SQL injection attacks so always be wary of what could be in those variables.

To print the query do:

```
$query = "UPDATE Users SET Level("$highScoreType") = $lvl,     Xp("$highScoreType") = $totalXp,   WHERE UserID= '1'"
echo $query
mysqli_query($con, $query)
```

Comment: It needs to be Level("$highscoretype") because the column title is Level and then overall/attack/defence etc for every column. Hence i just need to update level and then the specific skill. How would i go about echoing the query?

Comment: Why the brackets? Is 'Level(overall)' a column name or 'Leveloverall'?

Comment: This `mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Users SET Level` "IS" `mysqli_` @JonathanCrouch

Comment: Yep. i realised that about a minute after i posted. I think i'm going to retreat and re-read some textbooks...